# Gas hot water tank quit working and leaked

Tags: plumbing, leak, water-heater

I came home from work today to find that the hot water wasn't working. I opened the area to my gas hot water tank and there's a large pool of water on the ground. I checked the pilot light and it appears to have gone out.

I removed the pipe attached to the temperature and pressure release valve and tested the temperature and pressure release valve. Some copper colored water came out but soon ran clear. The water coming from the tank is not hot and I do not smell gas. There is what appears to be buildup around the temperature and pressure release valve. The tank is currently not leaking. Could this have quickly leaked water and caused the pilot light to also go out somehow?

[image: water tank temperature and pressure release valve] [image: water tank temperature and pressure release valve]

Any ideas to what could have happened and how to go about fixing it? Thanks

Comment: Time for a new one =].

Comment: How old is the tank?

Comment: What's the make and model of the unit?

Comment: State Industries, Inc. PR640N0DSV2. The tank is quite old. Manufactured in 1998 and in use in 1999.

Answer (score 1):

These are all signs that the tank has corroded through. Looks like you should be in the market for a new hot water tank.

Comment: Exactly what are these "signs" that it is rusted through? Wouldn't it be prudent to get more information and troubleshoot a bit before recommending the OP spend hundreds of dollars?

Answer (score -2):

One thing's for sure:

**Turn off the gas to the heater.**

The pipe may still be connected, and you're not smelling anything, but that pipe is **still pumping gas into the heater.** That's a **MAJOR** safety hazard, and if I were you, I'd get an electric heater, unless you have no other choice but to get a gas heater.

Comment: Gas heaters have pilot sensors that shut off the gas to deal with just such a situation.